# Intercept push notification from showing in app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I need to have a toggle for push notifications in my app, but I can't make changes in server. Can I intercept the push message in GCM and not show it in the topbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are the one displaying the notifications, you do not have to "intercept" anything. You are already receiving the GCM messages, with the code that you wrote, where your code is displaying the `Notification`. Simply have that code examine your `SharedPreferences` (or wherever the "toggle" is stored) to see if the code should actually display the `Notification`.